# Script for exporting objects to VRML

Tags: scripting, export

Does anyone know how to export objects to VRML by using a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender includes a [vrml exporter](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/VRML2), you just need to [enable it](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/addons.html).

[image: vrml addon]

Unless you specifically need the vrml format you might be better off using the newer X3D exporter (X3D is the successor to vrml).

If you need to automate the export with a script you can use the export operator once the addon is enabled.

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.export_scene.vrml2(filepath='myscene.vrml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an added note: ISO/IEC 14772-1 1997 is still available online, this is the formal specification for VRML2. I downloaded mine some years back and printed it off to have on hand. VRML works well in BLENDER but you have to remember scaling is not 1:1 vrml/blender! It might be in the view window and you cannot see it because it is teeeeeny tiny in the Blender world or totally out of range in size. The Handbook of specs is indespensible if you are going to work in VRML2. And good luck!